# Node engine version problem when deploying to vercel

Tags: deployment, next.js, vercel

So I had a nextjs project deployed to vercel, and today I committed a minor change that was deleting some console log statements and it wouldn't deploy anymore. It is throwing this error:

[picture of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTVFF.png)

> error ipfs-unixfs-importer@9.0.7: The engine "node" is incompatible
> with this module. Expected version ">=16.0.0". Got "14.19.0" error
> Found incompatible module.

I think it is because that ipfs-unixfs file needs node version 16+ but vercel only works with 14.x. What can I do to fix it?. Node only handles version 12.x and 14.x

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Currently, Vercel only supports node.js 12.x and 14.x - try using this treat suggestion: https://github.com/vercel/vercel/issues/1078#issuecomment-433377209

1. Add this file to the main project

> .yarnrc

and add any flag to it.

2. like:

> --install.ignore-engines true

Comment: This is an outdated answer. Vercel presently supports Node versions 14.x, 16.x and 18.x

Comment: vercel is only accepting version 18.x

Answer (score 4):

You need to update the Node version that Vercel is using for your project's build step. This can be easily done in the project settings. As described [in the Vercel Changelog](https://vercel.com/changelog/node-js-version-now-customizable-in-the-project-settings), go to your project on your Vercel dashboard, click Settings, and scroll down a bit until you find the Node.js Version dropdown option. Select 16.x and redeploy your latest deployment. This worked for me.

Answer (score -2):

I had a similar problem
and it was solved using

```
npm install node@latest
```